# World shaders disapearing in Blender File

Tags: rendering, hdri

In shading tab I created two settings for the world. One for a night, one for a day, [image]

but one is always disappearing after I reopen the file.

[image]

Is there a way to keep them both? I tried solving it this way:

[image]

However settings are suppose to be linked to 21 files. When I change something in the settings I have to append it in 21 files and I'm sick of that.

Comment: 1st what are you trying to achieve here? 2nd use link instead of append.

Comment: If I use link then I have to open the original file edit there nodes from day to night save it refresh library in the file that I want to do a render it. Then render the scene. If it is appended I simply edit it from day to night and do the render.

Comment: Why not make 2 world shaders then? just like materials, you could have so many world shaders in just one file.

Comment: That is the problem. When I make two word shaders one is always gone when I'm reopening the file.

Comment: sorry your question was a bit unclear before. I added my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender By default purges most unused data blocks. (this happens when you save and reopen the file)

Just add a fake user and it should remain in the file until it has no user (be it fake or not) and you save it or manually delete it.

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

file> external data> automatically pack into .blend